# Apollo 3 useQuery & useMutation causing Gatsby Build to crash

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, gatsby, apollo-client

I can run an app successfully in dev mode but whenever I try to build the app I get a

```
10 |     function InvariantError(message) {
11 |         if (message === void 0) { message = genericMessage; }
> 12 |         var _this = _super.call(this, typeof message === "number"
 | ^
13 |             ? genericMessage + ": " + message + " (see 
https://github.com/apollographql/invariant-packages)"
14 |             : message) || this;
15 |         _this.framesToPop = 1;


WebpackError: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: 46 (see 
https://github.com/apollographql/invariant-packages)

- invariant.esm.js:12 new InvariantError
node_modules/ts-invariant/lib/invariant.esm.js:12:1
```

- invariant.esm.js:24 invariant
  node_modules/ts-invariant/lib/invariant.esm.js:24:1
- OperationData.js:30 
  MutationData../node_modules/@apollo/client/react/data/OperationData.js.OperationData.refreshClient
  node_modules/@apollo/client/react/data/OperationData.js:30:58
- MutationData.js:38 MutationData../node_modules/@apollo/client/react/data/MutationData.js.MutationData.execute
  node_modules/@apollo/client/react/data/MutationData.js:38:45
- useMutation.js:27 useMutation
  node_modules/@apollo/client/react/hooks/useMutation.js:27:1
- ConfirmationButton.js:32 ConfirmationButton
  src/components/ConfirmationButton.js:32:44

error Command failed with exit code 1.

I have currently wrapped my components in the apollo provvider within the gatsby-browser file.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add isomorphic-fetch to the Apollo client in gatsby ssr and browser.

Comment: You are quite right that I should have left a comment instead. Fat thumbs on mobile I'm afraid. It is however the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `gatsby-plugin-apollo` did the trick for me: `npm install gatsby-plugin-apollo @apollo/client`.

```
// gatsby-config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-apollo',
      options: {
        uri: 'https://example.com/graphql'
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-apollo/#gatsby-plugin-apollo